# How do I rename all the occurrences of a particular XML element?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a XML file and it contains various `<b>` tags. I want to rename all the `<b>` to `<span class="ld_bold">` using linq but I only want to rename the element. I don't want to replace it's values.

I am using `StringBuilder` at the moment and reading the file line by line using `foreach`, which is why `<` and `>` are getting converted to `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively when I am loading the file using `XDocument`.

Comment: html shouldn't be in xml.

Comment: Using xml linq this is guaranteed to work in any situation :            List<XElement> bS = doc.Descendants("b").ToList();
            for(int i = bS.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                bS[i].ReplaceWith(new XElement("span",new object[] { bS[i].Attributes(), bS[i].DescendantNodes()}));
            }

Comment: It's perfectly legitimate (though of questionable value) for `<b` and `>` for such an element to appear across 2 lines. *Don't* process XML/HTML as strings and don't try to do it on a "line by line" basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `XDocument` to parse the XML, `.Descendants` to find all the **`b`** elements, and then manipulate those to your liking, as follows:

```
var xml = "<div><b>Hello</b><i><b>Goodbye</b></i></div>";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

foreach (var item in doc.Descendants("b"))
{
    item.Name = "span";
    item.SetAttributeValue("class", "ld_bold");
}

Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

***Demo:*** https://dotnetfiddle.net/3Yp6zx